# Finding the maximum number in a list python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, time-complexity, big-o

Below is my code to return the maximum number in the list, but for some reason it returns 9.

I must clarify that the aim of this program is to compare BigO complexities of quadratic - O(n^2)  with Linear O(n)  . So I am looking for a way to solve this problem with nested loop which will represent O(n^2). Please give a nested loop solution

```
a = [2,4,7,2,1,9,33,105,2,3,7,300,4,9]
maxa = a[0]
for i in a:
    for j in a:
        if (i>j):
            maxa = i
print("greatest number is   " + str(maxa))
```

help figure what the problem is

Comment: I must clarify that the aim of this program is to compare BigO complexities of quadratic - O(n^2)  with Linear O(n)  . So I am looking for a way to solve this problem with nested loop which will represent O(n^2). Please give a nested loop solution

Comment: Why do you think 2 loops are necessary here?

Comment: two loops are not necessary to solve maximum number in the list, my question is i need an O(n^2) function  to represent finding a max number. So I thought of nested loop because its an O(n^2) representation. If you have another quadratic function to represent the complexity of this problem, please suggest to me.  @PM2Ring

Comment: The task is linear, as several answers below show. You can add an extra loop, but it won't do anything useful. But I guess I can add an answer that does use 2 loops.

Comment: So is it impossible to represent task with quadratic function ? can i make this conclusion ?@PM2Ring

Comment: It's not impossible, just inefficient. If you _really_ wanted to, you could come up with ways that are even more inefficient. :)

Comment: yes,@PM2Ring . I think the aim of my question is not to find an efficient way. it is to find a quadratic representation of this task. I am writing a blog on  BigO notation and making comparison between linear and quadratic functions of the same algorithm. So my purpose is not to find most efficient. I already worked on the linear functions being given below.

Comment: Ok, I'll add another quadratic method to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't find the correct maximum, it simply sets `maxa` to the last value of `i` which is greater than some other item in the list.

Here's code that finds the correct maximum using a double loop, as requested, but the `j` loop is completely pointless.

```
a = [2, 4, 7, 2, 1, 9, 33, 105, 2, 3, 7, 300, 4, 9]
maxa = a[0]
for i in a:
    for j in a:
        if i > j and i > maxa:
            maxa = i

print("greatest number is", maxa)
```

**output**

```
greatest number is 300
```

FWIW, you could also write that test as

```
if i >= j >= maxa:
```

---

Here's an even worse way, although it's still quadratic. We scan through the list, swapping an item with the last list item if it's smaller than the item currently there. At the end of the scan, the item at the end of the list must be the minimum, so we discard it. We repeat this process until only a single item remains, and that must be the maximum.

```
a = [2, 4, 7, 2, 1, 9, 33, 105, 2, 3, 7, 300, 4, 9]
while len(a) > 1:
    for j, u in enumerate(a):
        if u < a[-1]:
            # Move this item to the end of the list
            a[j], a[-1] = a[-1], a[j]
        # The last item is the minimum, so we discard it
        del a[-1]

# Only 1 item is left, it must be the maximum of the original list
print("greatest number is", a[0])
```

**output**

```
greatest number is 300
```

Comment: Great answer because you show the OP where the went wrong.

Comment: @BlackFrog  Actually only PM2Ring was able tp  understand the question and generate right answer.. i was looking for a nested loop to represent quadratic complexity O(n^2) not necessarily an efficient linear complexity so indeed he ave the best answer

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use the [max](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#max) function.

```
>>> a = [2,4,7,2,1,9,33,105,2,3,7,300,4,9]
>>> max(a)
>>> 300
```

Comment: Thanks for @Giordano. But I must clarify that the aim of this program is to compare BigO complexities of quadratic - O(n^2)  with Linear O(n)  . So I am looking for a way to solve this problem with nested loop which will represent O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [2,4,7,2,1,9,33,105,2,3,7,300,4,9]
maxa = a[0]
for i in a:
    if i > maxa:
        maxa = i
print(maxa)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [2,4,7,2,1,9,33,105,2,3,7,300,4,9]
print(max(a))

Output
#300
```

Explanation:
The method max() returns the largest of its arguments: the value closest to positive infinity.